# Trying to get the highest goal scorer in a list of players, goals

Tags: c#

```
public class Player
{ 
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Firstname { get; private set; }
    public Ploeg Team { get; private set; }
    public int Goal { get; set; }
}
public class GlobalCollection
{
    public List<Ploeg> PloegCollection { get; private set; }
    public List<Speler> SpelerCollection { get; private set; }
}
public GlobalCollection()
{
        SpelerCollection.Add(new Speler("Stanciu", "Nicolae", p1 , 0));
        SpelerCollection.Add(new Speler("Massimo", "Bruno", p1 , 0));
        SpelerCollection.Add(new Speler("Hanni", "Sofiane", p1 , 0));
        SpelerCollection.Add(new Speler("Teodorczyk", "Lukasz", p1, 0));
}
```

I have a button who sets the goals +1.

```
    private void goalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ploeg1ListBox.SelectedIndex >= 1)
        {
            Player pl = (Player)team1ListBox.SelectedItem;
            pl.player++;
            GoalForm goal = new GoalForm(); //winform with picture
            goal.ShowDialog();
        }
```

now i want to show with a button click the highest goal scorer. I tried using maxvalue and so on..

```
  foreach(Speler sp in data.SpelerCollection)
  {
      for (int counter = 0; counter > data.SpelerCollection.Count;counter++)
      {
```

i can't seem to find the right code for my little program, could you help me guys?

Grts

Comment: If you have LiNQ you can use `Max` to get the highest scoring player.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
var playerWithHighestGoalRank = data.SpelerCollection
                                        .OrderByDescending(player => player.Goal)
                                        .First();
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
var maxGoals = SpelerCollection.Max( s => s.Goal);
Speler maxScorer = SpelerCollection.Where( s => s.Goal == maxGoals).First();
// rest of your logic ...
// you should handle the case, when more than one
// player have scored the same amount of goals.
// It would be better to get a collection back and then
// display the result depending on the number of players returned
```

Comment: Was about to comment that Single is probably not for the best. I'd just leave that out to return an `IEnumerable<Speler>` for the highest or joint highest scorers.

Comment: @Chris You are right, but he asked for a single object. But the op can change the answer to a collection fairly easy.

Comment: I prefer your `First` to `Single` anyway (the problem I had with `Single` being the potential for exceptions). :)

Comment: @Chris, yes changed that too. :-)

Comment: `First` can throw an exception if the list is empty.  `FirstOrDefault` will return the first item or `null` (technically `default(T)`) if the result is empty.